# Python CSV Has No Attribute 'Writer'

Tags: csv, python-2.7, nonetype

There's a bit of code giving me trouble. It was working great in another script I had but I must have messed it up somehow.

The `if csv`: is primarily because I was relying on a -csv option in an argparser. But even if I were to run this with proper indents outside the `if statement`, it still returns the same error.

```
import csv

if csv:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
            quotechar=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csvout.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C'])
        csvfile.close()
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import csv.py", line 34, in <module>
    csvout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'writer'
```

If I remove the `if statement`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\import csv.py", line 34, in <module>
    csvout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'writer'
```

What silly thing am I doing wrong? I did try changing the file name to things like test.py as I saw that in another SO post, didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you've set something that assigns to `csv` (looks like a string) then you're shadowing the module import. So, the simplest thing is to just change whatever's assigning to `csv` that isn't the module and call it something else...

In effect what's happening is:

```
import csv
csv = 'bob'
csvout = csv.writer(somefile)
```

Remove the further assignment to `csv` and go from there...

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for not seeing it sooner. I had a `csv = args.csv` elsewhere in the script. Thank you so much!! Changing the `if statement` to `if args.csv` and removing the previous `csv = args.csv` solved it. Excellent.

Answer (score 75):

For me I had named my file `csv.py`. So when I `import csv` from that file I was essentially trying to import the same file itself.

Comment: same for me too :-)

Comment: Same here ... (facepalm)

Comment: my face when ಥ_ಥ

Comment: *facepalm*-- @thameera thanks! changed my file to "not_csv.py" and now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

For my case, my function name happened to be `csv()`. Once I renamed my function, the error disappeared.