# Adding 'if' conditions into sorted dictionary set of data

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I am trying to make the following code work for producing a desired output. I suspect my error is in the format the code, so hopefully someone can help me with it (still very green to coding). Here is what I have coded so far:

```
import csv

infile = open("source.csv", "rU")
incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
outfile = open("sourceoutput.csv", "w")
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')
dict = {}
header = incsv.next()

rowNum = 0
for row in incsv:
    data1, data2, name, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data10 = row
    lastname = name.split(", ")[0]
    firstname = name.split(", ")[1]

if data1 == "1":
    #Adding (lastname, firstname, data3, data4, data5) of data1 = 1  only into dictionary 'dict'
    if lastname not in dict:
        dict[lastname] = firstname, data3, data4, data5

#Printing data sorted by lastname in alphabetical order
names = dict.keys()
sorted_names = sorted(names)
for name in sorted_names:
    firstname, data3, data4, data5 = dict[lastname]
    outcsv.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (lastname, firstname, data3, data4, data5))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I suspect there is an error where I defined the if statement which adds `(lastname, firstname, data3, data4 and data5)` into `dict` when `data1 == 1`. How do I implement this condition into the for loop and add the appropriate information into the dictionary for subsequent rearranging in alphabetical order? Is there anything else needed with the setup of my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the indentation of your code, `if data1 == "1"` is not inside the `for` loop. It is afterwards. Also, don't use `dict` for a name or you make it more difficult to access the built-in function `dict` later.

Comment: If I just put four blank spaces before the if data1 == "1", and do the same for the subsequent if lastname not in dict: etc would that work?

Comment: Im not sure if I can put an if condition and then another one right after it like I have in that section.

Comment: It might work. Try it and find out. You can indeed have an `if` right after another `if`, but for this particular situation it's more popular to use `and` to combine multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand by looking at your code, you need to add data to your dict for all rows of your CSV, so your `if` needs to be inside the for loop as shown below. (FYI: you can also combine both your `if` statements into one e.g. `if data1 == "1" and lastname not in dict:`).

```
rowNum = 0
for row in incsv:
    data1, data2, name, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data10 = row
    lastname = name.split(", ")[0]
    firstname = name.split(", ")[1]

    if data1 == "1":
        #Adding (lastname, firstname, data3, data4, data5) of data1 = 1  only into dictionary 'dict'
        if lastname not in dict:
            dict[lastname] = firstname, data3, data4, data5
```

Comment: Thanks schaazzz and everyone else! Here is what I developed but I get an error. I will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.writerow()` which is _csv.writer specific.

doc: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Edit: Take also a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069181/python-csv-has-no-attribute-writer).

Comment: Thanks Mornor. I did and it not has this dooley error message:  File "source.py", line 25, in ? firstname, pclass, sex, age = dict[lastname]
KeyError: 'Dooley'

I have no idea what this Dooley error is :(

Comment: Is there a `Dooley` somewhere in your `source.csv` file? (or somewhere else).

Comment: What is Dooley? I am scrolling through google and my notes and see no mention of this! Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: I think it is looking for 'key = Dooley'.. Can you print out your dict and sorted_names?